# What is the difference between JoinRoom and OpJoinRoom?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

Photon PUN2 has a bunch of API's like 'JoinRoom', 'JoinLobby' etc. And others that are prefixed with 'Op' like 'OpJoinRoom' and 'OpJoinLobby'. I do not see in the documentation what the difference is. eg here: https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_load_balancing_client.html#a0b09d2933f50f7f956f7f3a2b56664c1
I see it used in examples, with no explanation. eg here: https://doc.photonengine.com/en/server/current/reference/calling-operations

What is the difference between these sets of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik that's just a matter of different API levels within the Photon architecture.

[`JoinRoom`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/PUN/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#a9566119590af99d455f43df68f74d65a) is a member of `PhotonNetworking` which is part of `Photon.Pun` which stands for "Photon Unity Networking" -> this is a Unity specific layer build on top of the core Photon Realtime engine.

[`OpJoinRoom`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_load_balancing_client.html#a0b09d2933f50f7f956f7f3a2b56664c1) is a direct access into the underlying `NetworkBalancingClient` which is part of `Photon.Realtime` and which is afaik what `JoinRoom` will call at some point.

So it's a little bit comparable with a high level and a low level API.